# codeigniter form validation always returns false even when rules met

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, submit

Problem: even if my form fields meet the rules the codeigniter form validation still returns false (error).

example:

```
   public function edit(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required|xss_clean|trim|is_unique[news.Title]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'description', 'required|xss_clean|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('notes', 'notes', 'required|xss_clean|trim');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['error'] =  '';
        $data['page_title']="Edit News";
        echo "error";

    }
    else {
    ..........
```

if i leave the fields empty it will tell me to enter something because they cant be left empty. if i type something then it returns error once i submit the form.

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Try changing `news.Title` to `news.title`.

Comment: In first part of if than block you should load your form view in case form_validation failed.

Comment: `fields ==which field`? you should print which validation it fails

Comment: The only thing that would throw an error in your case is the is_unique function. This is what's causing the problem.  Like others have suggested check case-sensitivity, make sure DB columns exist, with the little code you supplied it's hard to tell as you didn't post the appropriate code segment for us to confirm/deny it is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the callback validation function

you have to pass id also

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|xss_clean|trim|callback_check_title');

function check_title($title) {        
    if($this->input->post('id'))
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
    else
        $id = '';
    $result = $this->news_model->check_unique_title($id, $title);
    if($result == 0)
        $response = true;
    else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_title', 'Title must be unique');
        $response = false;
    }
    return $response;
}
```

in model

```
function check_unique_title($id, $title) {
    $this->db->where('title', $title);
    if($id) {
        $this->db->where_not_in('id', $id);
    }
    return $this->db->get('news')->num_rows();
}
```

it will work for both insert and update

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: thanks. i forgot to pass the $data when when loading the view in case of error.

Answer (score 1):

no need for callback function

The problem is : codeigniter database class is not loaded;
You should load database : $this->load->database(); before running

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $data['error'] =  '';
    $data['page_title']="Edit News";
    echo "error";

}
```

Comment: Oops! Was doing exact same error. As I was in need of `database` everywhere I added this `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` in `config > autoload.php` fixed my problem